# Twisted DNS query error when running with sudo

Tags: python, linux, twisted

I'm new in python and I'm playing with Twisted.
I have write my example that queries the dns record from the DNS server likes that:

```
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.names import client, dns
from twisted.python import log

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)


def do_lookup(domain):
    a = client.query(dns.Query(domain, dns.CNAME), [2])
    a.addBoth(lookup_done)


def lookup_done(result):
    log.msg(result)


myloop = task.LoopingCall(do_lookup, 'myzone.example')
myloop.start(0)
reactor.run()
```

Running this tool by: `python test.py` It works well.

But, I got a lot of errors about the DNSError when running with sudo: `sudo python test.py`

```
[DNSDatagramProtocol (UDP)] [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.names.error.DNSNameError'>: <Message id=42061 rCode=3 maxSize=0 flags=answer,recDes,recAv queries=[Query('myzone.example', 5, 1)] authority=[<RR name= type=SOA class=IN ttl=10015s auth=False>]>
```

Please share me something if you're saw/fixed that problem